# Failed to generate certificate and provision file with iOS certificate wizard

Tags: codenameone

I want to generate a certificate and provision file with cn1 certificate wizard but I get an error message.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming this is happening in the final stage of the process, right?

Login to your Apple account and try to generate a certificate via the web interface. For most cases this will trigger an error that will lead you to an agreement you haven't approved yet. Once you do that the certificate wizard should work.

Also check out the output in the IDE while running Codename One Settings (assuming you're using maven). There might be more detailed error messages in the console that can be useful for debugging.

Comment: I use Ant.
This happens at the beginning of the certificate wizard when I try to log in.
I have approved all the agreements.

Comment: In that case do you have more than one device on the two factor authentication? Can you reach the certificate UI in the web?

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how to handle the certificate on the web without the certificate wizard.

Comment: You don't need to. If you can go to the page responsible for the provisioning and certificates and start going through the process of downloading a CSR or generating a provisioning profile it means the account is fine. If you can't then you should get a proper error message.

Comment: Yes, I can download the centificate(development.cer) successfully.

Comment: You need to try and generate a CSR. Let's try a different approach. Try creating a project on start.codenameone.com with the same package name and main name. Then run Codename One Settings there so you can see the output printed to the console. Do you see an error there?

Comment: Yes, It generates certificates and provision files successfully with Maven. Where can I download the sample projects in Maven? For example charts, porker, and phonenix.

Comment: Those are no longer available but you can either copy the certificate/provisioning to the Ant project or take the plunge and migrate to maven. In both cases it's just copying the relevant files to the new location.